# Unity: Canvas spawning off of Scene

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas

When I spawn in a UI object my Canvas spawn with the bottom left corner at 0,0 on my scene. I want it to overlay the scene correctly, BUT if I switch hit Render Mode: Camera is does not properly overlay the UI. Is there a fix for this?

[image: Canvas View]

[image: Canvas Settings]

Comment: Did you try to set the position to `0,0,0`? And can you show us the settings for the image/panel?

Comment: In general I think it would be better to use `Screenspace - Camera` instead and reference your camera

Comment: Canvas cannot be moved by changing those values, I tried this but when doing it - it makes my images disappear due to the z position. I tried moving my game area to match and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to change the Canvas Scaler to Scale With Screen Size.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried this but when doing it - it makes my images disappear due to the z position. I tried moving my game area to match and it does not work.

Comment: Is there a way to make my images still overlay with that setting?

Comment: Can I have a screenshot?

Comment: It is provided.